# How to allocate a non-copyable and non-movable object into std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmap

I have an object that I want to restrict to be allocated only inside of a `std::map`. Here is the simplified code:

```
#include <map>

class Value
{
public:
    Value(int value) { _value = value;}
    Value(const Value&) = delete;
    Value& operator=(const Value&) = delete;
    Value(Value&&) = default;     // ***
    void* operator new(size_t) = delete;    // not on free store
private:
    int _value;
};

class Container
{    
public:
    Container();
    Value* addToMap(int key) {
        auto ret = _map.emplace(key, key);
        return &(ret.first->second);
    }
private:
    std::map<int, Value> _map;
};
```

In order to make it compile on Mac using CLang I had to add a line marked by asterisks requesting default move constructor. However this line causes C2610 error when compiled in Windows Visual Studio. Looks like VS2013 C++11 non-compliance includes inability to generate default move constructors. Is there a different way for me to allocate an object inside of standard map that would compile across platforms or do I have to implement my own move constructor?

Comment: Why do you want to add this restriction?

Comment: I want the object to be owned exclusively by container and prevent other code from calling new and delete.

Comment: You are mixing objects and data structures. If user of your data structure wants to copy the object, why not?

Comment: The nature of my objects is such that I don't want them to be uncontrollably copyable or movable. I have a network of mutually dependent objects of several types and in order to enforce validity of network topology I need to limit the way how objects are brought to life and destroyed. In some sense my reasons are similar to reasons why people want to use unique_ptr to store their data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An option is to use [`std::piecewise_construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct):

```
Value* addToMap(int key) {
    auto ret = _map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct
                          , std::forward_as_tuple(key)
                          , std::forward_as_tuple(key));
    return &(ret.first->second);
}
```

[**VC++ DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ZMVY53573)